# How can I show the signature of a constructor in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ide, signature

So, there is a feature in Eclipse that when you create a new class (or call a method), you can see the method signature above the code line, and you can use tab to go through the arguments. But if you press enter, or, in the case of the method signature, if you click anywhere, it goes away.
My question is: How can I get this back? This feature is especially usefull when having large constructors and no builder class. Is there any shortcut through which I can enable this behaviour again?

Comment: Do you mean Ctrl+Shift+Space?

Comment: Which is bound to the function "context-information".

Comment: @howlger Thanks, that was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you mean ***Show Context Information*** (**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>**) to show the type and name of the parameters of a method call or of a constructor as tooltip.

Comment: Here is your marked answer. You have earned it.